# How to use a python program stored in a text file?

Tags: python

I'm making a troubleshooting program in which I need to take a python program which is stored in a text file, but I can't use the 'import' module. To clarify this, there would be a python program stored as a '.txt' file, and in the main program I would take this text file and be able to use it as a subprogram. I've tried doing this, but I have had no clue of how to go about it, especially since I do not have much experience of Python.
Below is roughly the program. I don't know how to format it either, but here goes:

```
phonechoice = input("What type of phone do you have?")

if 'iphone' in phonechoice:
    #here I would load a text file which contains the program for the iphone
    #which asks them what problem they have with their phone and gives a solution
```

I'm wondering how I can do this. I thought how I could do this and maybe I could 'copy and paste' the program, line by line, into a definition, which I could then use. Would this work, and if it doesn't then in what other way could I do it?

Comment: Could you use a .py file and import that? If you do you should be able to use it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `eval`  `myfile.read()`, which is a terrible thing to do. I smell an XY problem. Exactly why do you want to do this? How does this fit into your overall workflow?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I don't understand, because although this was what I was thinking, my teacher said that I can only use a text file, which I see as a much more convoluted and harder way of doing it.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I agree with you. `eval` for an entire fill would be very risky and have a lot of potential problems.

Comment: It's quite hard to explain - I need to load up a text file (which is actually a python program) and then use it that way.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. You should try to figure it out on your own if you really want to **learn** Python, not just kind of know it.

Comment: What I understand is that filename.txt or filename.py, both are text files regardless the extension. When you import a file, you import a text file.

Comment: So I could still technically 'import' it that way? @Mantxu

Comment: You don't import .txt files you read them.

Comment: MarkyPython is right as well. I am not sure if it could be valid for your propouses.

Comment: So once I've read a .txt file could I then store it in a definition which I could then use? @MarkyPython

Comment: I have a feeling that there's some detail of the assignment that got lost in translation when you posted your question. I recommend actually quoting your assignment here, so that we can make better sense of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the text file to a python file, i.e. change the extension to ".py".  This does not change the fact that it is a text file, just like renaming a picture.jpg file to picture.txt does not change the fact that it's an image file.

If you have some wacky requirement to import a module saved in file with a .txt extension, you can not use an import statement.  But it is still possible to import like this:

```
import imp
my_module = imp.load_source('my_module', 'example.txt')
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something here, but the actual program repeats indefinitely - is there a way I can only do it once? @wim

Comment: Sorry @wim ignore that - I was experimenting earlier and I didn't realise that I was actually copying and pasting the code into the same text file. I had >20 of the same program which is why I thought it repeated infinitely.

Answer (score -1):

I am a bit reluctant to answer a "homework" type question, but I will give you some pointers on what you need to do. If I have a text file with this in it:

```
def main():
    print("Hello")

main()
```

I could execute the code with the `exec` function like this:

```
with open("filename.txt") as file:  #filename should be the name of the file
    data = file.read()

exec(data)  #this executes the code
```

The output would be as expected:

```
Hello
```

Hopefully this will shed some light on your problem!